# Cant access site after installing certbot

Tags: certbot

I'm having a problem with certbot where I cant access my site anymore after setting it up. When using the domain, i get a prompt to login to my gateway. When trying to acces a specific page, I get a `403 forbidden` error. Ik that there are other questions like this but they wernt helpfull.

Things I've tried: renewing the certificate, checking the date/time settings, restarting certbot.